# Local variable 'contacts_data' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

When I trying to call the method POST, it successfully creates, but I get the error's message in my serializers. What I should do, to get success when I call this method in my RESTful API?

Serializers.py:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    if 'branches' in validated_data:
        branches_data = validated_data.pop('branches')
    if 'contacts' in validated_data:
        contacts_data = validated_data.pop('contacts')
    course = Course.objects.create(**validated_data)
    branches_list = []
    contacts_list = []
    print(contacts_data)
    print(branches_data)
    for branches_details in branches_data:
        branches_list.append(Branch.objects.create(
        course_id = course.id,
        **branches_details))
    for contacts_details in contacts_data:
        contacts_list.append(Contact.objects.create(
        course_id = course.id,
        **contacts_details))
    course.save()
    return course
```

Comment: the problem is if `'contacts'` is not in `validated_data, `contacts_data` won't be defined by the time you are trying to use it, print it in this particular case. The same is going to happen with `branches_data`.

Comment: What I should be doing?

Comment: @DanilPopopv, what should be the case when `'branches'` is not in `validated_data`... I mean the condition is up to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that `branches_data` and `contacts_data` are lists, so in case they are not present, they should be declared as empty lists. The following code will run:

```
def create(self, validated_data):

    branches_data = validated_data.pop('branches') if 'branches' in validated_data else []

    contacts_data = validated_data.pop('contacts') if 'contacts' in validated_data else []
    course = Course.objects.create(**validated_data)
    branches_list = []
    contacts_list = []
    print(contacts_data)
    print(branches_data)
    for branches_details in branches_data:
        branches_list.append(Branch.objects.create(
        course_id = course.id,
        **branches_details))
    for contacts_details in contacts_data:
        contacts_list.append(Contact.objects.create(
        course_id = course.id,
        **contacts_details))
    course.save()
    return course
```

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I tried but not happens because I have less than 15 reputations ( Thank you again for your response!